# How are you transporting the minimum number of golf clubs while travelling?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, trekking, sailing

I am trying to find a method to get my 3 loved golf clubs -- putter, wedge 56 and iron 6 -- with me during traveling without needing to take the whole bag. I am sailing, flying, trekking -- so carrying a real golf bag is not an option. I like to use them for all kind of fun during casual travelling. I currently use [100liters' Duffel bag by Hagor](http://www.varusteleka.fi/fi/product/hagor-keikkalaukku-100ltr/16352) but it is not long enough to get wedge/iron6 inside. The Hagor bag is an excellent durable bag but just short enough not to store the 3 golf clubs. I am not getting my 3 golf clubs with me if I need to pay repetitively the golf bag fee. According to the length guidelines such as [Norwegian](http://www.norwegian.com/uk/kundeservice/Reiseinformasjon/bagasje/), it is technically possible to have a bit longer luggage. I was considering an option of adding extra pouches to Hagor and have the clubs along the back i.e. use them as support to the back but I don't want to make holes to the waterproof canvas so some special gluing would be needed. So

> **How are you transporting the minimum number of golf clubs while travelling?**

Comment: Btw. I once bought a tester club where it had the removable club face -- it may be the solution. Get 3 tester clubs to the bag with the opener so they may make into the current duffel bag.

Comment: Downvoter, it would be a good idea to comment as to why you think this post is not up to the mark. IMHO this is a completely legitimate post.

Comment: Maybe this is a daft question, but wouldn't it be easier to rent golf clubs? Or is that not a thing?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid a lot of people really  get used to *their* clubs, and don't want to rent a set.

Answer (score 1):

There are several travel golf bags that will protect your clubs in the hold, as bags can get thrown around quite a bit.  For example, [Bagboy has two hard-cases](http://www.tydaniels.com/packing-golf-clubs-flight/).  Hard cases are recommended over soft as some airlines won't pay for damage caused to clubs in soft cases.

If you want a cheap option, some pvc piping to protect the clubs, wrapped inside a soft bag may be the budget and lighter way to carry them.

A final alternative is the international golf club shipping company [ShipSticks](http://www.shipsticks.com/).  There's a [review by Forbes on the company](http://www.forbes.com/sites/larryolmsted/2013/08/30/for-golfers-shipping-clubs-now-beats-flying-with-them/) if you'd consider that.